# Written widget for ubuntu 13.04 on HTML5 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ubuntu, widget

How can I create some widget for ubuntu desktop based on HTML5 and JavaScript?

[image]

It should look like Webframe screenlet, but as standalone application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/) allows you to, "Create multi-platform desktop apps with HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript". It also supports Python, PHP, and Ruby. In addition if you code Java Applets those can work as well as long as Java is installed of course.

You can't get rid of the main window though like your screenshot shows. You may have to code a browser yourself, and have the page show in there.